# gate control clock generation

Tags: verilog, clock, fpga

Here is the code first...

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
if(cstate==idle)    rclk<=1;
else rclk<=0;
end

always@(negedge clk)
rclk<=0;
```

What I want to achieve is this: every time at the rising edge of clock signal, if the signal cstate equals idle(4'b0000), the the rclk goes to one, else to zero, at the same time, every time the falling edge of clk will set the rclk to zero. THIS CODE IS NOT SYNTHESIZABLE since the compiler gives the error " the rclk signal is driven by multiple drivers".

How can I achieve the same function by other techniques?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a clock gate cell. Based on a 1 cycle wide enable signal generate a clock pulse which has the same high time as the input clock.

A naive way of doing this might be :

```
assign rclk = (cstate==idle) ? clk : 1'b0 ;
```

Which could easily be synthesised `assign rclk = (cstate==idle) & clk ;`
`cstate == idle` is going to glitch which is why it would normally be used by a flip-flop allowing the answer to settle before being used.

Using a clock gate cell stops you from creating glitches on the (rclk) clock line. It is common to instantiate your libraries clock gate cell in the rtl for this. In RTL it might be similar to :

```
reg result;
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    result <= 1'b0;
  end
  else begin
    result <= (cstate == idle);
  end
end

assign rclk = (result) ? clk : 1'b0 ;
```

This means result will be stable for each clock cycle, not allowing glitches through from the comparator.

**Expanded answer**

I have included my example again below with waveform, I have replaced your state comparison with a simple counter which overflows to reset itself. Not the comparison is matching to 2'b10; which means the clock appears on the following count (2'b11). If the clock was to appear in exactly the same time your comparison matched then you have no glitch suppression on your clock and will likely generate unreliable hardware.

```
reg [1:0] counter = 0;

always @(posedge clk) 
  counter <= counter+1;

reg  result;
wire result_a = (counter == 2'b10 );

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    result <= 1'b0;
  end
  else begin
    result <= result_a;
  end
end

assign rclk = (result) ? clk : 1'b0 ;
```

[image: Example waveform of Clock Gate]

Comment: Thanks for you help! I tried the combination way just like you posted by it didn't function properly. I guess the reason is that the rclk triggered by the EDGE of clk means that it is affected by the signal before the posedge of clk. In a combination way you won't have that effet.

Comment: I modified the code in the following way: I changed the sensitive list from posedge clk to clk, which I think would make is into a combination circuit. It works well in simulation but I wonder if it is realizable? Thank you for time!

Comment: always @ clk, will effectively be a combinatorial circuit not giving you the glitch suppression you really need for clock control.

Comment: @vitocarlos I have expanded answer and added a waveform to show what I would expect to see.

Comment: The code you gave has this problem: suppose that next state will make the enable signal 0, but the enable signal is zero only AFTER the posedge clk, which means that at the time the clock rises, the enable signal is still high and will produce a rising edge in rclk(at least in simulation...) and as soon as the clk sets at one the enable signal is down and the rclk is down as well. This in simulation will provide a "hidden rise edge" I think...My later design used the way you introduced but I really would like to learn how to handle these problems. Thank you!

Comment: @vitocarlos I do not really understand your issue from the comment, you are showing a good inclination to understand the problem, creating a new question would allow you to be more descriptive.

Using sequential or synchronous logic you should not have to worry about the sequences of things changing just after the clock. When dealing with signals interpreted as clocks it is worth paying attention to detail though. For now I would suggest reading up on clock gate cells.